# Make USB output device accessible across (Windows) network?

Tags: networking, usb, network-shares

I've just bought a Silhouette Cameo 3 cutting machine. It can only connect via USB. But I want to make it available to all Windows computers on our home LAN.

How?

So far I have come across these options, but feel unsure which will work and which will be most cost effective:

1. Wireless USB: So far haven't been able to discern if this is a dead end, and if it's not: will it solve my problem the way I want? How would it work? What hardware would I need?
2. Network attached print server, like e.g. [this one](https://www.tp-link.com/us/products/details/cat-5525_TL-WPS510U.html). Unclear if this will work, because the device is not a printer. Maybe it works anyway? Known issues with this kind of solution?
3. Place a small "headless" computer there, which I administer via remote desktop, SSH or similar. Most cost effective would probably be Linux, maybe a Raspberry Pi. But I don't know Linux, and I don't think there are Linux drivers available for the Cameo. Also not sure if devices shared from Linux will work with Windows clients. If using Windows, is Windows Home sufficient, or would Pro or other be required (license terms...)? What hardware would work for the Windows case? Stick computer? Think client? Important that it's quiet....

Other suggestions welcome, as well as explanaions of what will work and what will not.

Comment: Check the control panel when the USB cutting machine connect to computer, and refer to the link to check if it it available to set it as a share  machine. https://www.wikihow.com/Share-a-USB-Printer

Comment: @Joy, It's not a printer and it's placed on a separate table with no computer next to it.

Comment: I've bought a small ethernet connected USB server. I think it makes the remote USB ports appear as local to the client computer. I'll report back when I've had time to try it.

Answer (score 1):

To share a USB device you need third-party software.

You can find a list of six such products in the article
[List of 6 best USB over Ethernet solutions](https://www.eltima.com/best-usb-over-ethernet-apps/), dating from August 2018.

They are all commercial except for the
[USB/IP Project](http://usbip.sourceforge.net/).
Although dating from 2011, it is still listed and so might still be functional.

I have never worked with any of these products, so cannot help you choose.
In any case, product recommendations are not allowed on our site.